# TYPO3 copying IRRE child records

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I want to copy custom records, which have some child records, which themselves also have children. I build my TCA-Structure with IRRE in TYPO3.

How is it possible to copy the parent-record and all the children. With copying I mean create also new child-records and set them as child from the parent.

For now the references to the original records are set during copying a record, but this is not the behavior I want!

Answer (score 1):

IRRE (Inline Relational Record Editing) integrates 1:n relationships in TYPO3. The basic concept follows the composition pattern, means that child entities cannot exist without their parent. In a result child entities are copied automatically with their parent - and vice-versa are deleted if the parent is deleted. You'll find more configuration details in the [TCA documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write custom code to support this - I fear.
You can hook into TCEmain, but you might need to create custom action for this.

Comment: Might be a bug nevertheless, please follow the TYPO3 channels. But I am not sure ``how`` it is suposed to work.

Comment: Either it is done in TYPO3 6.2. Or look at flux extension from fluidTYPO3.org.